# How to "get" system proxy settings?

Tags: firefox, proxy, vpn, system, environment

I want to set proxy in my system firefox from firefox that I use by VPN.

in VPN's firefox in Preferences/Advanced/Network/Settings
the checkbox
"use system proxy settings" is checked.

where are system proxy settings definded?

Answer (score 1):

Global proxy setting can be defined on the following file: `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, or alternatively you may export proxy settings, please see: [apt.conf](https://askubuntu.com/a/349765/476968) and  [exporting](https://blog.mypapit.net/2006/02/how-to-use-apt-get-behind-proxy-server-ubuntudebian.html)

Answer (score 0):

On your Firefox browser select '**Edit**' and move to '**Preferences**' go to '**Advance**' and select '**Network**'. To the right-hand side '**Connection**'(with configure how Firefox connect to the internet) there is '**Settings...**', click on it and and check '**Manual Proxy Configuration**' and set your proxy manually.

Then,if you meant to see your system connection information do the following:

Right-click on your network icon on your system panel, at the extreme top corner of your screen and move down to 'Connection Information and select it to see your connection information.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question. The question was "Where are system proxy settings defined?" I tried selecting "Connection Information" from the network icon as suggested, but it doesn't say anything about the proxy configuration.